# Using subroutines to return values?

Tags: return-type, fortran

I'm currently learning FORTRAN (I am familiar with MatLab) and I am very confused about the point of subroutines. Why would anyone use them as opposed to functions. Also, how is it that they can return values when called in the main programs? For example:

```
PROGRAM SUBDEM 
    REAL A,B,C,SUM,SUMSQ 
    CALL INPUT( + A,B,C)
    CALL CALC(A,B,C,SUM,SUMSQ)
    CALL OUTPUT(SUM,SUMSQ)
END

SUBROUTINE INPUT(X, Y, Z)
    REAL X,Y,Z
    PRINT *,'ENTER THREE NUMBERS => '
    READ *,X,Y,Z
    RETURN
 END

SUBROUTINE CALC(A,B,C, SUM,SUMSQ)
    REAL A,B,C,SUM,SUMSQ
    SUM = A + B + C
    SUMSQ = SUM **2
    RETURN
END

SUBROUTINE OUTPUT(SUM,SUMSQ)
    REAL SUM, SUMSQ
    PRINT *,'The sum of the numbers you entered are: ',SUM
    PRINT *,'And the square of the sum is:',SUMSQ
    RETURN
END
```

My question is essentially, how do I know what each subroutine is returning?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you might be the first person to try to learn FORTRAN in 40 years.

Comment: @Snowman: Fortran is alive and kicking in numerical-heavy areas. If you wonder what powers the nice hip things like `numpy` and `scipy`, it's partially old pal Fortran. OTOH it's reasonable to learn [Fortran 90/95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fortran_90), not Fortran IV. I believe Fortran 90 allows you to pass / return parameters in more sophisticated ways.

Answer (score 7):

In Fortran, a subroutine "returns" everything you pass to it.  You can think of it almost like a C Macro.  In this:

```
 SUBROUTINE CALC(A,B,C, SUM,SUMSQ)
```

The subroutine "returns" `A`, `B`, `C`, `SUM`, and `SUMSQ`.  (Really, it just modifies the values passed to it in-place.)

In contrast, `FUNCTION` works like a C function, creating locals and returning a single value, which is what people used to more modern languages typically expect.

Comment: Note: You can change what gets returned by defining the `intent` for each variable.

Answer (score 2):

As a rough guide, functions are generally used to enclose a small segment of code that has no side-effects. For example, we can write

```
x = 2*foo(a) + foo(b)/4
```

if the order of execution is not critical (either because of no side-effects or the side-effects don't influence the result). If the code segment is large and/or contains many side-effects, it might be better to use a subroutine. A subroutine call is always a separate statement and thus the execution order is always unambiguous.

A subroutine is like a C function with a void return type and with some arguments passed by reference (by default all, actually). Ignoring good style and code safety, it is in principle possible to use only functions or only subroutines when writing modern Fortran.

Comment: Good answer!  Just made a minor edit to make the formulation of a sentence clearer to me ...